# Why does creating object inside the class invoke another function instead of $this?

Tags: php, foreach

```
    public static function instantiation($row){
 >>>   $users = new self;
    foreach ($row as $the_attribute => $value) {
      if($users ->has_the_attribute($the_attribute)){
         $users ->{$the_attribute} = $value;

      }
    }
    return users;
  }

  private function has_the_attribute($the_attribute){
      $object_properties = get_object_vars($this);
      $array_result = array_key_exists($the_attribute, $object_properties);
      return $array_result;
  }
```

May I know why do I have do create an object to here in order to invoke `has_the_attribute()` function? What is the problem here if I use `$this->has_the_attribute` and `$this->$the_attribute` instead of `$users->$the_attribute`?

Answer (score 1):

When iterating `$result` you get pairs of attribute-name/attribute-value, so `$the_db_attribute` is the variable containing the current attribute-name.

In `$the_object -> $the_db_attribute = $value;` we guess that `$the_object` has properties which are attribute-names.
So if current `$the_db_attribute` is, say, `"the_first_attribute"`, then your puzzling line is equivalent to `$the_object -> the_first_attribute = $value;`, which is not puzzling at all now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's assigning a property whose name is the value of `$the_db_attribute`, and setting its value to `$value`. So if `$the_db_attribute = "foo"`, it's equivalent to

```
$the_object->foo = $value;
```

So what this is doing is filling in the properties in the object with the corresponding elements in the `$result` array.